# Is it appropriate to bootstrap a linear model on rare event data when not always all factor levels of independent variables are present?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

I'm starting to have doubts regarding my approach to bootstrap a linear model on my rare events data. On repeated sampling, sometimes not all factor levels from a variable are represented and then this doesn't show coefficients. Because of unequal lengths, this causes problems when trying to create a matrix/data frame which allows me to create mean / confidence intervals from the obtained coefficients.

My example shows a generalised linear model, because this is what I am using in real life, but the same problem would happen with a "simple" linear regression `lm`. My real data has approximately 2000 events in ~90000 observations, and the problem occurs only with specific variables that have many factor levels. I decided to leave those problematic variables out of the equation, as they are luckily also not very relevant, but I wondered about the general question.

```r
foo <- data.frame(event = c(rep(T, 98), rep(F, 2)), 
                  v = letters[1:2])
foo$v[1] <- "e"
mod <- glm(event ~ v, data = foo, family = "binomial") 

bootstrap <- function(mod, n_boot = 2) {
  set.seed(1)
  array_coef <- replicate(n_boot, expr = {
    bdat <- foo[sample(nrow(foo), size = 40, replace = TRUE), ]
    bfit <- update(mod, data = bdat) ## refit with new data
    coef(bfit)
  })
  array_coef
}

## of course showing all factor levels
coef(mod)
#> (Intercept)          vb          ve 
#>  3.87120101  0.02061929 13.69486748

## not always showing all coefficients, I assume because the non-represented factor levels are being dropped
bootstrap(mod, n_boot = 2)
#> [[1]]
#>  (Intercept)           vb           ve 
#> 2.656606e+01 4.415089e-06 2.046100e-22 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> (Intercept)          vb 
#>    21.56607   -18.62163
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: There's a fundamental conceptual issue here: because bootstrapping uses the empirical distribution to model the population, the risk of mis-characterizing rare events (or missing them altogether) in the sample means it makes little sense to use bootstrapping to analyze those rare events, by their very definition (of "rare" meaning "unlikely to appear in a sample this size sufficiently often to give reliable information").

Comment: Thanks @whuber that's very helpful. And if I make the boot sample size very large, as in my example say 80-90k ? I wonder what other options I would have for obtaining confidence intervals, but I guess that I will need to do some more reading into it. Thanks for your help, highly appreciated.

Comment: The size of the bootstrap sample is irrelevant, because the issue is that the actual data themselves are not likely to sample the rare events in the population adequately.  One test is to run the bootstrap several times and to compute several different kinds of bootstrap confidence intervals: with rare events you will find that either the bootstrap sometimes fails altogether (you get warning messages from the software) or the intervals vary appreciably.

Comment: thanks @whuber, this is a great suggestion. I will do that.

Comment: (P.s. Maybe, with an observed frequency of approx 2%, my events are also not all that rare ... [?])

Comment: Right: an event observed 2000 times in a batch of independent observations will vary approximately by $\sqrt{2000}\approx 45$ from one batch to the next (this is one standard error).  That means you can be fairly sure of its true frequency to within about 5% (two standard errors, more or less).